# Why domain.com appears as theplant.com when hosted on hostgator?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

I have a script that's supposed to detect the url of its caller website. If the caller is another website, it should give something like `http://callersite.com`. I'm using this line of php code (though I suspect this won't matter for sysadmins)

```
gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

I'm testing with a caller site that's hosted on hostgator. What I'm noticing though is that I don't get `callersite.com`, I get something like `1a.12.12ab.static.theplanet.com`. I don't know what `theplanet.com` is and why I'm not getting `caller site.com`.

Also what do I need to do to really get the domain of the site making a call to my script?

--

Thanks for the explanation. Some have advised I use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it's not what I'm after. My script acts as an API. Another website makes a curl request to it and gets an output and later on presents it to the user. So http referrer gives `false` since the caller site.com is making a direct call to me. So any hope?

Answer (score 5):

Hostgator servers are hosted in Theplanet DC, now Softlayer, thats why you get 1a.12.12ab.static.theplanet.com as host name. The user doesn't have RDNS(or on shared) which is what

> gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])

gets so its getting theplanets default.  You could look at this which will pull the address the user came from.

> $ref=@$HTTP_REFERER;

Comment: Good one Jacob! ;) +1

Comment: +1 but unfortunately `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` isn't what I'm after. Let me explain: my script acts as an API. Another website makes a curl request to it and gets an output and later on presents it to the user. So http referrer gives `false` since the caller site.com is making a direct call to me. So any hope

Comment: So you want the domain correct? If your only getting an IP than you may be out of luck

Comment: You could have a signup for your api generate that a hash and deny anyone without a hash to identify.

Answer (score 2):

"gethostbyaddr" gets the reverse dns for a connection ip address. What you are probably looking for is the referrer, which is available in echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

Comment: +1 but unfortunately `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` isn't what I'm after. Let me explain: my script acts as an API. Another website makes a curl request to it and gets an output and later on presents it to the user. So http referrer gives `false` since the caller site.com is making a direct call to me. So any hope

Answer (score 1):

gethostbyaddr does a reverse lookup of the IP address. If this IP address belongs to an ISP provider, in this case theplanet.com or softlayer.com, then you will get a pointer to a generic name they defined.

callersite.com is just an alias for that IP, but not the real name or pointer.

If you are on linux, try

```
dig callersite.com
```

or on Windows

```
nslookup callersite.com
```

Or go to a page like http://www.dnsqueries.com/en/ and start your DNS queries there.

Comment: He doesn't have the domain but needs to find it from the IP

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to add extra headers to the request with curl. If the other side can modify their script they could just append the information you need. Since you're building an API just make the extra header part of the specification.